# Интеграция в сайт приватного видео c YouTube

Tags: php, yii, google-api, youtube-api, платежи

Скажите пожалуйста, есть ли возможность интегрировать приватное видео в свой сайт используя [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)?

Хочу сделать следующее: после оплаты открывать доступ к просмотру приватного видео.

Есть ли решения?

Comment: А в чём именно заключается проблема с приватным видео? И почему бы просто не проверить?

Comment: приватное видео находится на канале. А авторизация происходит по client_id и secret_key. Как получить видео которое приватное, не получается